# Request and save API data using setInterval in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, setinterval

Ive been trying to populate my var with data received from API using request module in nodejs and update my var every certain period of time using setInterval. However, I cannot update or save data into a global variable. When console log the var, it only shows empty arrayy []. please help me out!

```js
setInterval(function() {
 request("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP&tsyms=USD,JPY", 
 function(error, response, body) {
      var update = function(){
       
       dataCollections = JSON.parse(body);
      
      };
      update();
  });
}, 4000);

var dataCollections = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataCollections = [];
var loopRequest = setInterval(function () {
request({
url: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?
```

fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP&tsyms=USD,JPY",
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 10000,
    followRedirect: true,
    maxRedirects: 10
    }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
    dataCollections.push(JSON.parse(body));
    } else {
    console.log('error' + response.statusCode);
    }
    });
    }, 4000);

Answer (score 0):

You are not pushing the response data to your var, refer to the below code which does this:

```
setInterval(function() {
 request("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP&tsyms=USD,JPY", 
 function(error, response, body) {
      var update = function(){

       dataCollections.push(JSON.parse(body));      
      };
      update();
  });
}, 4000);

var dataCollections = [];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! When I tried to consonlog data collections, it still shows me an empty array.. Also, I am not trying to keep pushing data to the array because im trying to use the var passed to EJS which will work like a price board real time. Any better solutions?? Im planning to also use setInterval on EJS to refresh my price board page everytime..

Answer (score -1):

`dataCollections.push(JSON.parse(body));`

**Edit:**

Call you update price board method inside interval,it will update/refresh your price board every time

```
setInterval(function() {
 request("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP&tsyms=USD,JPY", 
 function(error, response, body) {
      var update = function(){

       updatePriceBoard(JSON.parse(body));  //It will Update/Refresh your price board    
      };
      update();
  });
}, 4000);

function updatePriceBoard(){
  //Your Business logic...
}
```